# Copy_To_SQL command is throwing error when I am passing a valid schema name

Tags: pandas, teradata

We are trying to copy the data frame to Teradata specific database and the script is not accepting the schema_name parameter. Data Copy to  User Database, which used in logon command is happening. But I tried to override the default and specifying Database Name in the copy_to_sql it is failing.

```
from teradataml import *
from teradataml.dataframe.copy_to import copy_to_sql

create_context(host = "ipaddrr",    username='uname', password = "pwd")

df = DataFrame.from_query("select top 10* from dbc.tables;")
copy_to_sql(df = df ,table_name = 'Tab', schema_name='DB_Name',if_exists = 'replace')

Error: TeradataMlException: [Teradata][teradataml](TDML_2007) Invalid value(s) 'DB_Name' passed to argument 'schema_name', should be: A valid database/schema name..
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database / user named `DB_Name`?  If not, try creating the database first and then running your copy script:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE DB_NAME FROM <parent_DB> AS PERMANENT = 1000000000;
```

I don't think the utilities / packages will typically create a database for you on the fly, since it can be a more involved operation (locks, space allocation, etc.) than creating a table.

Comment: Can you verify that the user you're using to login to the `TD` system in your script has permissions to create tables in the database in `schema_name`?

Comment: Yes, my user has permission.